# Is Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * unsafe?

Tags: ajax, http, rest, cross-domain, cors

My application's backend is an API serving JSON content. I've found the need to apply the following Response Header so that it allows requests from anywhere:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Is this unsafe?

How else do you create a public API without running into the restricted cross-domain origin policy? I need to allow both `GET` and `POST` requests to my API endpoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is practically a necessity if you want to expose your API.  It is inherently insecure, and even specifying domains can cause problems because it would be simple for someone to spoof the Origin header getting around your whitelist anyway.

In other words, using `*` is not much less secure than whitelisting domains.

Instead, you need to make sure that you have other security measures in place to make sure that requests are properly authorized as needed -- especially write requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance. Can you give me an example of what you mean by other security measures? Do you mean sanitizing database inputs?

Comment: @izolate in particular I was talking about making sure that the request comes with some sort of authentication token proffered by OAuth or something.